# Adjective that means under constant / frequent change

Tags: single-word-requests

I would like to find a suitable adjective to describe a leader board that has changed frequently. Of course the leader board *can* change, but it doesn't have to -- the possibility of entrenchment / solidifying positions is also a distinct outcome. With this in mind, I want to draw attention to the fact that it has in fact changed this time around.

> A ______ leader board suggests firms are ramping up operations.

I considered using "dynamic" / "volatile" here, but dynamic sounded too vague and volatile seemed a bit unnatural.

Comment: 'Changing' itself will do. 'Volatile' raises few eyebrows when used of a fast-changing situation even outside the chemistry lab ... but the changes are drastic. 'Motile' is getting fancy.

Comment: changing, evolving...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are basically looking for is a word that means both these things: One, that the leaderboard is changing, and two, that it's changing for the better (because the firms are ramping up operations).

Keeping this in mind, I suggest that you go with *progressive*

> **Progressive:**
>
> - of, relating to, or characterized by progress
> - making use of or interested in new ideas, findings, or opportunities

[Merriam-Webster Dictionary]

Comment: Progressive often refers to gradual improvement, and certainly doesn't imply fast change. For instance progressivism is often contrasted with revolutionary change: the former is slow, incremental improvement, the latter sudden and rapid.

Answer (score 0):

A **live** leader board suggests firms are ramping up operations.

**Live** (adj.)
MW:

Definition of live (Entry 3 of 3)
: at the actual time of occurrence : during, from, or at a **live** production the program was broadcast live.